# Index of a maximal subgroup among normal abelian subgroups

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups, abelian-groups, p-groups

> Let $P$ be a $p$-group and $A$ maximal among abelian normal subgroups of $P$. Show that:
>
> 1) $A=C_P(A)$.
>
> 2) $|P:A|\mid (|A|-1)!$.

1) If $A$ is an abelian normal subgrup of a certain group $G$ then also $C_P(A)$ is. In fact let $x\in C_P(A)$, let $g\in G$ and consider the quantity
$$(gxg^{-1})a(gxg^{-1})^{-1}=gx(g^{-1}ag)x^{-1}g^{-1}$$
By normality of $A$:
$$gx(g^{-1}ag)x^{-1}g^{-1}=g(g^{-1}ag)xx^{-1}g^{-1}=a$$
So by maximality $A=C_P(A)$

2) This is more complicated:
I must use properties of $p$-groups, for example
$Z(P)\cap N\neq 1$ for $1<N\triangleleft G$, there are subgroups of all intermediate cardinalities...
But i was not able to combine them together with the information given in 1).

Comment: Are you sure of (2)? Because $\;[P:A]\;$ is a power of $\;p\;$ , whereas $\;(|A|-1)!\;$ is not, if I'm not wrong.

Comment: Your proof if 1) is not quite right because $C_P(A)$ is not necessarily abelian. 2) follows from 1) because $C_P(A) = A$ implies that $A/C_P(A)$ induces a group of automorphisms of $P$ by conjugation.

Comment: Ok. So 2) follows quite simply.
For 1:
Abelianity is not necessarily preserved.
I know that $<A,g>$ is abelian for all $g\in C_P(A)$ but normality is not preserved in this case.
Another strategy can be using this fact:
In a $p$-group P for all $N<M$ normal subgroups it's always possible to find an intermediate $L\trianglelefteq  G$ such that $N\subseteq L\subseteq M$ and $|L:N|=p$.
If $A\subseteq N\subseteq C_P(A)$ then $N$ must be abelian. In fact taken $x,y\in N$ we can write $x=g^ea$, $y=g^fb$ with $a,b\in A$.
These elements commute